# How to authenticate soap header using php (not using nusoap)

Tags: php, soap

How to authenticate soap header using php (not using nusoap)

**This is the soap header**

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <user xsi:type="xsd:string">soapuser</user>
        <password xsi:type="xsd:string">soappassword(MD5)</password>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try looking to the Soapheader class : http://php.net/manual/fr/class.soapheader.php